# Rotation number of composition

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations

Let $f,g:S^1 \to S^1$ be orientation-preserving homeomorphisms. Consider the lift $F,G:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. Let $\rho(G)$ and $\rho(F)$ be a rotation numbers. What we can say about rotation number of  their composition? i.e about $\rho(F\circ G)$. I know that if $F$ and $G$ are commute then $\rho(F\circ G)=\rho(F)+\rho(G)$. But what if not? For example if $\rho(G) = \rho(F)=0$ then what can we say about $\rho(F\circ G)$?

Answer (score 5):

Write $S^1=\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z}$. Denote by $\mathcal{G}$ of increasing self-homeomorphisms of $\mathbf{R}$ commuting with the translation $z\mapsto z+1$, that is, whose graph is invariant by the translation $(x,y)\mapsto$ $(x+1,y+1)$. So the rotation number $\rho(F)$ can be defined as $$\rho(F)=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{F^n(x)-x}{n},$$ which does not depend on $x$. Your question amounts to ask which values of $\rho(G\circ F)$ are possible when $\rho(F)=\rho(G)=0$:

> The answer is: $[-1,1]$.

Indeed, since $\rho(F)=\rho(G)=0$, they have fixed points $x_F,x_G$, we can suppose $x_F\in [x_G,x_G+1\mathclose[$. Fix $x\le x_F$. Then $F(x)\le x_F\le x_G+1$, and in turn $G\circ F(x)\le x_G+1\le x_F+1$. By induction, $(G\circ F)^n(x)\le x_F+n$. This shows that $\rho(G\circ F)\le 1$. The inequality $\ge -1$ follows by a similar argument, or applying this to the inverse.

Conversely, all values in $[-1,1]$ are attained:

- how to obtain $\pm 1$: Consider $F$ fixing 0 and mapping $1/4$ to $3/4$. Conjugating by the translation $+1/2$, we define $G$, fixing $1/2$, and mapping $3/4$ to $5/4$. Hence $G\circ F$ maps $1/4$ to $5/4=1+1+4$, which implies that $\rho(G\circ F)=1$. Passing to the inverse, we also obtain $-1$.
- how to obtain $t$ with $-1<t<1$: Let $R_t$ be the translation by $t$. Choose $F$ with the prescription that $F(0)=0$ and that there exists $x$ with $F(x)=x+t$ (this is possible because $|t|<1$). Define $G=R_t\circ F^{-1}$. Then $G(x+t)=R_t\circ F^{-1}(x+t)=R_t(x)=x+t$, so $\rho(F)=\rho(G)=0$, while $\rho(G\circ F)=\rho(R_t)=t$.

Answer (score 3):

@user3421341,Theorem 3.9 in the paper of [Calegari and Walker](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.0080.pdf) gives a complete answer to your question, for arbitrary values of $\rho(F)$ and $\rho(G)$.

Comment: Thanks! to help reading, they define $X(r,s)$ [denoted there $X(ab,r,s)$; I drop $ab$] as the set of possible values of $\rho(FG)$ when $\rho(F)=r$ and $\rho(G)=s$, mention it's a compact interval of the form $[\rho(F)+\rho(G)-R,\rho(F)+\rho(G)+R]$ for some $R=R(ab,r,s)=R(r,s)$. Then $R(r,s)$ is characterized in diophantine terms in Theorem 3.9. I don't think it can be called a "complete answer". It's rather a "complete translation  of the question into a diophantine problem". Which shows that the question is is highly non-trivial!

Comment: By the way their result (which would be nice to copy in your post) implies that $R(r,s)\le r+s+1$, which I haven't been able to check (I only get the trivial bound $R(r,s)\le r+s+2$).

Comment: You're completely right, @YCor: it's an explicit formula, but it's not a closed one. So maybe it's not a "complete answer"... but it's a nice one! :)

Comment: Yes it's a nice one and also it's an answer in the sense of this site, since it shows that it's not some naive closed formula (I expected we always get the interval $[r+s\pm 1]$). On the other hand, it would be welcome to copy the formula in your post, and maybe provide some explicit computations or inequalities of $R(r,s)$... beyong $R(0,0)=1$ and $R(r,s)\le 1$ (case of equality?)